# Binary tree in C - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, binary-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nod{
    int data;
    struct nod *left,*right;
}NOD;

NOD * generate(NOD * root)
{
    NOD *r,*p;
    int d=-1,value,line,position,i,f,v;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        do{
            printf("Would you like to create the root node?\n\n1 - yes\n0 - no\n");
            scanf("%d",&d);
            switch(d)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Value=");
                    scanf("%d",&value);
                    root=add_root(value);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Command unrecognized!\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while(d==-1);
        if(root!=NULL)
                printf("Root node successfully created!\n");
        else
            printf("Error: could not create root node!\n");
        d=-1;
        do{
            printf("Continue adding nodes?\n\n1 - yes\n0 - no\n");
            scanf("%d",&d);
            switch(d)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Insert the line and the position of the node you wish to add (root node has line=0, position=0)\nLine=");
                    scanf("%d",&line);
                    printf("Position ( less or equal with 2^$line-1 )=");
                    scanf("%d",&position);
                    printf("Value=");
                    scanf("%d",&value);
                    r=p=root;
                    for(i=line-1;i=0;i--)  
                    {
                        f=power(2,i);
                        if(position & f == f)   // if the i-(st,nd,rd,th) bit of "position" is 1, then (position & f == f) is true and *r will go right
                        {
                            p=r;
                            r=r->right;
                            v=1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            p=r;
                            r=r->left;
                            v=0;
                        }
                    }
                    if(v==0)
                        p=add_left(&r,value);
                    if(v==1)
                        p=add_right(&r,value);

                    break;
                case 0:
                    return root;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Command unrecognized!\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while(d==-1);
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }

NOD * add_left(NOD **p,int value)
{
    NOD * r;
    r=malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    r->data=value;
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
    (*p)->left=r;
    return r;
}

NOD * add_right(NOD **p,int value)
{
    NOD * r;
    r=malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    r->data=value;
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
    (*p)->right=r;
    return r;
}

NOD * add_root(int value)
{
    NOD * x;
    x=malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    x->data=value;
    x->left=NULL;
    x->right=NULL;
    return x;
}

}
int main() {
    NOD *root=NULL;
    root=generate(root);
    return 0;
}
```

---

I tried make a program that creates a binary tree but I keep getting SIGSEGV Segmentation fault and I don't understand why. Can you please tell me what I did wrong?

```
if(position & f == f)   // if the i-(st,nd,rd,th) bit of "*position*" is 1,
                        // then (position & f == f) is true and *r will go right
```

What do you think about this part?

- *line* is the level of the tree (root has line=0)
- *position* is the position of node from left to right (root has position=0)

Comment: Please try to narrow the problem down, and use a debugger. As it stands, this is a *lot* of code to go through for what will probably amount to some basic misunderstanding of the fundamentals of C, or perhaps a simple error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have bolded a problematic part:

```
if(position & f == f)
```

`==` has higher precedence than `&`, so that is parsed as

```
if(position & (f == f))
```

and is the same as `if (position & 1)`, not what you want.

Further, you have the wrong loop condition

```
for(i=line-1;i=0;i--)
```

the test should probably be `i >= 0`, otherwise the loop is never executed (`i = 0` is an assignment that evaluates to 0).

If these are fixed and the loop is executed, after the first iteration `r` is a nullpointer, then the next loop iteration causes the crash in `r = r->right;`, or, if the loop iterates only once, `add_left(&r,value);` (or `add_right`) dereferences a nullpointer on the penultimate line trying to access its `left` (resp. `right`) pointer:

```
NOD * add_left(NOD **p,int value)
{
    NOD * r;
    r=malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    r->data=value;
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
    (*p)->left=r;          // *p == NULL here
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Agree.The compiler is confused at '&'

Warning 7 warning C4554: '&' : check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence

Comment: @Cristi Oh, right, overlooked that in the wall of code. However, once you invoke `r = r->right;` more than once, you have an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Cristi To really find the cause of the segfault, one would need to see `add_root`, `add_left` and `add_right`. At the moment, it's too much guessing.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
for(i=line-1;i=0;i--)
```

I think you meant

```
for(i=line-1;i!=0;i--)
```

Otherwise the loop will not execute (`i=0` evaluates to `false`). which causes `v` to have undefined value (as it is never initialized).  While this most likely will not result in segfault, it will cause memory leak as you overide the left/right subtree of the root.

Also, the default `switch` branch does not change the scanned value of `d`, which means you proceed with a `NULL` root (the error branch that checks for `root != NULL`) does not exit the function)